# In ANGULARJS on: s.Id as s.Name for s in Players show playerName in {{expect player-name instead of Id}}

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I need to show the `Name` instead of `Id`,now in UI I get `Id` for Player::::

**In EditDialog.Html**

```
<select class="form-control" style="display: inline-block" name="ssDll" ng-model="Rocker.PlayerId" ng-options="p.Id as p.Name for s in Players" required>
    <option value="">Select Players</option>
</select>
```

**In app.js File on particular controller :**

```
$scope.Players= [
    { Id : 1, Name : 'Player1' }
];
```

**In main.html when I bind all things to main page :**

```
` <td>{{Rocker.PlayerId}} </td>`
```

**what should I pass here to get the Player name in Main Page :**

Answer (score 0):

try like this

```
   <select class="form-control" style="display: inline-block" name="ssDll" 
ng-model="myColor" ng-options="team.Id as team.Name for team in Players" required></select>
```

you can check documentations [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngOptions)

see working [plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/pJ5MlCj6fnn6SLaD8uLG?p=preview)

Comment: While this code sample may possibly answer the question, it would be preferable to include some essential explanation to your answer. As it stands now this answer adds little to no value for future readers.

Comment: No it didn't worked. It shows the same output, only id is displayed

Comment: Currently selected: {{ {selected_color:myColor} }} in this my color i m getting Id where i need to have the name. instead of 1,2,.... I need to show player1,player2 . .. . . . ..In dropdown i see options player1 player2 thats perfectly fine, but now while binding in {{ }} this i need to show player1 if player1 is selected not their Id's as 1

Answer (score 0):

You have to change the ng-model name and is it Id or _id.

```
<select class="form-control" name="ssDll" ng-model="p" ng-options="p.Id as p.Name for p in Players" required>
<option value="">Select Players</option>
```

Sample

```
                    <select name="test" class="form-control" ng-model="item.account"
                        ng-selected="item.account"
                        ng-options="accounts._id as accounts.name for accounts in projectAccounts"
                        ng-required="true">

                </select>
```

Hope this helps.